# Android Listen Home button

Tags: android

Is it possible to listen home button uniquely, if the application contain some default intent? I have checked life cycle method but it will execute when I am starting the default intent and home button.

Answer (score 6):

An acticity can have more than one intent filter. so in the manifest add another intent filter like this to listen fro home button.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

try this let me know

Comment: @Varun A context menu appear for this filer and say complete your action using either the Homebutton or The application ,nothing is listen in application

Comment: now it pop up for my every application when i press the home button

Comment: Yes this is how it will work. since now there are more than two applications listening for the home button, a popup will be shown to select the application. and since u have made ur app as the default app it will launch ur app whenever the  home button is clicked

Comment: or tell me clearly when do u want to override the home button?

Comment: when the user press the home button and resuming the operation i need to perform dbsycing

Comment: u want to override the home button when your application is running or all the time? and when u override the home button do u show any UI or u want to do something in the background?

Answer (score 1):

> when the user press the home button
>   and resuming the operation i need to
>   perform dbsycing – Sudeep SR Dec 6 '10
>   at 12:45

It sounds like you want to override the onStop or onStart methods of your activity.  There are things other than the home button that can cause your application to exit (sent to background).  The back button, camera button, incoming phone call, selecting an item in the pulldown notification bar. I don't think you want to rely on just the home button exit case. Here's the activity lifecycle link that is always good to reference in these situations: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife

Comment: Onstop and onStart other life cycle method is common to the starting or ending new activity and pressing home button ,i need to uniquely identify that user press the home button, i think life cycle method can't help me, becoz my application contain lost's intent ,so it difficult to identify using the life cycle method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a global static boolean flag that will tell you if exiting the Activity was intended.
You need to raise that flag in any "finishing" procedure. (exit procedures / back key pressed).
Here is an example:

```
 /**
 *  Home Event
 */
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        StaticClass.exitFlag = true;
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
public void onUserLeaveHint() { // not executed when answering a call
    if (StaticClass.exitFlag)
        StaticClass.exitFlag = false;
    else
        // Home was pressed!!!
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
/**
 *  End Home Event
 */
```

This way you control when and how you exit the activity.
There are only two ways for the activity to disappear without your knowledge
and thats by answering a call or by pressing Home.
This example eliminates the option for answering a call with the onUserLeaveHint() event!

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the thread necromancy, but is there a bug in _onUserLeaveHint()_?  The formatting of the code implies _super.onUserLeaveHint()_ should be called regardless of _exitFlag_'s value, but the code will only execute _super.onUserLeaveHint()_ if _exitFlag_ is false.

Comment: sorry for the late reply... but for future reference, the line after else implies you insert your own code and the 'super...' line will be outside of the if-else statement.