# Android - Resume application from background programmatically

Tags: android, performance, background, onpause

i need to resume my app as soon as the application goes in background.

I don't like my solution cause has a few bugs and is not too performant, this is what i try:

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is a single Activity application which load a webview with many dynamic and flash content  while update his state every few seconds and every few second get information from web.
So is not to simple and fast every time it goes in background to recreate the activity.
To relaunch application needs about 3-4 seconds, too much for me. If users between that seconds clicks the settings icon in the home, application doesn't start again. I don't know why and i'm writing here after a lot of googling :) Help me please!

Comment: So whenever the user has something other in the foreground than your activity, you want to launch your activity again? Does not sound like it fits in the Android framework. Please have a look at this [Android Developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). You may instead want to use a `Service`. Please look it up.

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Use a background service instead.

Comment: how can i use service to do what i need?

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `android:persistent="true"` in the `<application>` element in your Android manifest, but I am under the impression the Android OS will ignore that request if your application is not installed as part of the default system image.

The Android SDK documentation says specifically "Applications should not normally set this flag; persistence mode is intended only for certain system applications." You would also chew up a lot of battery. Android specifically is not designed for there to be any good way for applications to stay running when they aren't being used, so that the OS can multitask properly and so that battery usage stays reasonable. Services can be set to run in the foreground (`Service.startForeground()`) but then they are required by the OS to provide a widget in the notifications area so that users are aware that the service is always on.

For what it's worth, users on mobile devices are more tolerant of delays than users on desktops, so it may not be as bad as you first think.

Answer (score 1):

i think what you want is to implement a home screen replacement. basically, you add an intent filter to that your app responds to the intent that is broadcast when the user presses the home key. you can read more about it here.

> [Android Listen Home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365312/android-listen-home-button)

note that if you do this, you user will at least get a chooser asking them whether to run your app or the standard home screen app. the user can choose to make your app the default home screen app if they want.

that being said, unless you have a very special case like you are building a software / hardware combo device that is dedicated to your application, you almost certainly don't want to do this. what CommonsWare said is correct in this regard. if you try to take over the device, you will most certainly be rewarded with an uninstall, or angry emails from less tech savvy users that you happen to trick into making your app the default home screen.

Answer (score 0):

> So is not to simple and fast every time it goes in background to recreate the activity

When the user presses HOME, your process sticks around for a while. If the user returns within a few minutes (or, perhaps, even hours), your process will still be around, and the user will be returned to your activity.

If, however, the user leaves for a substantial period of time, or the user does a lot with their device (e.g., runs a bunch of apps), Android will terminate your process to free up memory for the other things that are going on. Exactly how long a "substantial period of time" is, or how much is "a lot with their device", will depend on a variety of factors, such as what other apps they have running, how much RAM is in their device, what the per-app heap size is (tied to Android OS version and screen size), and so forth.

What you are attempting -- poorly -- to do is to force the user to never leave your app. You are saying that you are more important than your users. Your users will likely disagree with your attitude.

You may be able to help your cause by slimming down your app, so that it takes up less memory. One way to do that, and to help yourself for the long term, is to get rid of the "flash content". By this time next year, there is a decent chance that a majority of your users will be unable to run your app, as Flash is no longer available for Jelly Bean and higher. Launching the Flash plugin is also slowing down your activity's start-up time.

Beyond that, for any application logic outside of your WebView, you can use Traceview to try to figure out where your time is being spent, to try to improve performance.

Comment: I'm developing this app for a small circle of tablets used in some  business activity in my town. The tablet and my app act as "advertising" :)